# opencart - information_id not displayed

Tags: opencart

I'm in the "informations" and must display the *information_id* to do a check. But the code below does not.

```
echo $this->request->get['information_id'];
```

I did the following test and returned it right:

```
print_r($this)
```

But when I do this below, returns null

```
print_r($this->request)
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: It must be because it's in a loot (opencart loves it's loops)

In what file are you fiddling with the code? And what version of OC?

Comment: I'm changing the information.tpl and header.tpl

Comment: are you using 2.0 OC or earlier?

Comment: can you explain what exactly is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: The client asked me to put a banner in the header (where the logo is), but each _information page_ will have a different banner.
I thought about doing a check by _information_id_ to know which page the user is and display the correct banner

Comment: Well i dont really know the structure of OC 2.0.3,if u cant find what you need can't you try with the header of the information page?
Lets say Info page name is  Bananas 
So you do an if statement if(header_title == Bananas{do this}{else do that so on and so forth? not sure how 2.0 displays header titles though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve.
I had to change the controller/information.php in function  index() added the following information:

```
$data['inf_id'] = $information_id;
```

inside if($information_info)

And after that, I can take the *information_id* within the informationt.tpl

tks